# How to remove this ridiculous amount of space between page editing?

Tags: spacing, texstudio

Title says it all.
I had a similar file without that much space, it actually had 1 cm separation between pages when editing.

[image: Spacing]

Comment: Which PDF viewer is this?

Comment: It's the TexStudio compilation window... There are no problems in Okular, as an example... but editing this in TexStudio is becoming a pain...

Comment: I can sort of reproduce it in TeXstudio 2.12.14 with `\documentclass{book} \usepackage{pdflscape} \begin{document} foo \begin{landscape} bar \end{landscape} \end{document}` (I get less space), so perhaps the internal viewer in TeXstudio doesn't quite handle rotated pages properly. If it's always the same for you, that it happens between portrait and landscape pages, I think I'd suggest posting a bug report at https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues

Comment: I will look into this right now and see if I fix it, thanks @TorbjørnT.

Comment: Problem goes away when I use \documentclass{book} but landscape A3 pages are gone. The weird thing is that I have the exact same preamble in another document and I guess there's something up here...

Answer (score 1):

Okay. I got it working. I think the problem is having an A3 page among A4 pages in **portrait** mode. If you insert a landscape A3 page, then this size will not **supersede** the A4 height, since **A3 in landscape is the same size as A4** in height, then it will display uniformly.   In the case, this was the offending section:

```
% beginning of commands to create a page size A3
\clearpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=a3, pagesize}
\recalctypearea

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \makebox[\textwidth][c]{
        \includegraphics[height=\textheight]{fig3}}
    \caption{Examplo of graphics inserted in a A3 page}
    \label{fig4}
\end{figure}

%Return to A4
\clearpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=a4, pagesize}
\recalctypearea
%-- A4 continuation
```

[image]